# Function not setting inner HTML in a Bootstrap popover content div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that sets the inner HTML of an id to the users email. It works perfectly fine when adding the div in normal Html body, but when I try to display it in a popover it doesn't show anything.

```
<body onload="userIGaccount();">
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
          placement : 'top',
          trigger : 'hover'
      });
  });
</script>

    <i class="far fa-question-circle fa-xs icon-position" data-html="true" data-toggle="popover" title="Account Information" data-content=" Email: <br> Instagram Account: <span id="userIGAccount"> </span> </i>
    // I want to display the users email in "<span id="userIGAccount"> </span>"
    function userIGaccount(){
        let e = "<?php echo $_SESSION['login_user'] ?>";
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "--urlremoved--",
            success: function(data) {
                const obj = JSON.parse(data)
                let x = obj[e]
                document.getElementById('userIGAccount').innerHTML = x
            }
        });
      }
</body>
```

Comment: console errors?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the value for `data-content` is getting truncated because it contains a double-quote character which is treated as a delimiter:

```
data-content=" Email: <br> Instagram Account: <span id="
```

Try using single quotes in the embedded HTML to avoid that problem:

```
data-content=" Email: <br> Instagram Account: <span id='userIGAccount'> </span>
```

The element with ID `userIGAccount` will only be accessible via the DOM when the popover is displayed.

Comment: There's also no ending double-quote at the end of the attribute.